# How do I change the formatting of a cell using a formula

Tags: excel, formatting, excel-formula

I want to know if it is possible to make a formula which changes the formatting of a cell. For example, the heading of my table is called `allocation` and using Data Validation there is a small drop-down box so the user can chose from several different headings. Depending on which heading the user chooses, the data will change using an IF statement, for cell C3:

```
=CONCATENATE( IF($C$2="allocation"; B3; ""); IF ($C$1 = "rate"; A3, ""))
```

Right now it looks like this:

```
    A              B             C
1               
2 rate       allocation   allocation v
3 $45           100%          100%
4 $39            50%           50%
5 $29           100%          100%
```

but if the  user chooses the drop-down list (represented by the `v`) then he gets the choice `rate` which should look like this:

```
    A              B             C
1                              
2 rate       allocation          rate v
3 $45           100%             $45  
4 $39            50%             $39  
5 $29           100%             $29
```

but instead it shows all rates as percentage (`4500%` for example).

Important:
I can do it with text, but I really need the values, because I want to sum them at the end.

How do I make Excel change from percent to currency using a formula, i.e. without having to do with manually (and hopefully without using VBA)?

Comment: Conditiional formatting with two separate rules works for me. Not quite sure if that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

First, your formula does not look right as it mixes semicolons with a comma as separator and refers to C1. I take it you meant:

```
=CONCATENATE( IF($C$2="allocation"; B3; ""); IF ($C$2 = "rate"; A3; ""))
```

which I think might be abbreviated to:

```
=IF(C$2="rate";A3;B3)
```

though I appreciate you may in practice have a requirement for a longer formula in view of additional items in your drop-down list (though I’m not sure where other items would be located).

Second, you mention *I can do it with text, but I really need the values, because I want to sum them at the end*. This may mean that you find the following unsuitable:

```
=IF(C$2="rate";TEXT(A3;"$0");TEXT(B3;"0%"))
```

Though I am not sure why you must sum ColumnC rather than whichever of ColumnA or ColumnB is relevant. (I am assuming those two columns are Currency and Percentage format respectively).

Third, that leaves @Tom’s suggestion, i.e. Conditional Formatting where the value in C2 sets the formatting for C3 and cells lower down, with the formula something like `=IF(C$2="rate";A3;B3)`. For which please select ColumnC and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=C$2="rate"
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, Number, Currency, Decimal places: `0`, Symbol: `$`, OK, OK, OK.
There is no need for a second CF rule as ColumnC may be formatted Percentage as standard.

Comment: In countries where , is used as the decimal separator, all forumulas use semicolon instead as parameter delimiters (I'm in Sweden by the way)

Comment: Hi Pnuts. 1) In countries where , (comma) is used as the decimal separator, all forumulas use ; (semicolon) instead of commas for the "parameter delimiters" (e.g Sweden)  2) you understood right.  Let's just say this was a simplified example and not get into why I need it.  3)  The conditional formatting worked just fine as you and Tom said.  I was simply not aware that conditional formatting could do this, I thought it could only handle colours, and other "fancy stuff" like bars and symbols!   Thanks for the help!